# How to enable being able to move tiles and launch as another user in the windows 8 start screen

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

I'm on a fresh windows 8 install and as part of an early roll-out program it happens to be customized for a normal user, where as I'm a developer. I would like to be able to move tiles and customize my start screen, and notably launch applications as administrator or with another user account.

My current configuration does not allow me to move start screen tiles simply clicking and holding a tile and trying to move it. When I try to drag a tile, nothing happens. Same with groups. When right-clicking a tile two times, the lower menu pops up with only one single button to the right called "All apps", whereas I have seen on windows 8 screenshots that there should be more options, like "Run as different user" etc. (for example [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/114708/how-to-run-windows-8-apps-as-a-different-user-from-the-start-screen/), for which I have followed the instructions but with no change whatsoever).

The local "Administrator" account does not have these restrictions - the menu appears with several options upon right-click, tiles can be moved using the mouse.

My user account is a member of the local Administrators group.

How/Where can I change these restrictive settings for my user account?

Comment: Desktop icons work fine. I'm talking about start screen icons/shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Create a new user, give it Administrator permissions, see if the problem exists.  This a personal pc or company workstation?